# How to get the total time in seconds of a video in opencv

Tags: opencv

Is there any `CAP_PROP_*` to find the total time in seconds of the video ?
Or do I have to divide total frames by fps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9955/i-want-to-display-time-in-my-video-using-opencv/).

> You can also get the length of the entire video in seconds from
>   CV_CAP_PROP_FPS and CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT.

Comment: Thanks. But thats why I meant by divide total frames by fps

Comment: You have to do that. There is no property for giving the time directly (I didn't find one).